# Soap header exception in c#

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl

We are using a soap service for communication between server and client. We have written a function in wsdl of the server for this.
When we try to run the code for the client, we are getting an exception saying that function doesn't exist. It is showing soap header exception when we debug the code.
Kindly help us in this issue.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Typo in function name? Wrong XML Structure/Schema? Namespacing issues? How shall we know w/o seeing WSDL and the request made?

Comment: So what is the name of the method you are trying to call and what is the specific error?

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that you refer to the right function, you should have used add ServiceReference by right clicking the project in Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

I never wrote WSDL myself. Instead, you may write a mirror .NET Web Service and use the automatically generated WSDL (by MS Visual Studio).